# Running python script from PyCharm Robot Framework

Tags: python, scripting, robotframework

I have some experience with Robot Framework but not with running Python files from an RF test case. In this situation, all I'm trying to do is have my HelloWorld.py file display "Hello World" while running the RF test case setup. Here is my code.

Python file

`HelloWorld.py`

`print("Hello World")`

Robot Test Case

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       GradApp Regression
Library             Zoomba.GUILibrary
Library             Process
Resource            ../../Pages/resource.robot
Suite Setup         App Setup       ${url}  ${browser}

*** Variables ***
${browser}          chrome
${url}              https://app.test.com/

*** Keywords ***
Python Script Test
     ${fish}=  Run Process       python   C:\PyCharm\Automation\HelloWorld.py
     Log To Console              ${fish}

App Setup
     [Arguments]                 ${url}  ${browser}=${browser}
     Open Browser                ${url}  browser=${browser}  
     Log To Console              Setup complete.
     Python Script Test

*** Test Cases ***
TC 001 Basic Case
     <UI Keywords after Setup is complete.>
```

When this code test is run, I don't get an error. I just get a display of <result object with rc 2> in the console. I need to just see Setup Complete display and then Hello World right below it. I can't understand why I'm seeing the <rc 2> message.

I have looked at some other solutions and none of them seem to address this particular issue. Is my library wrong? Is "Run Process" not the right keyword? I would appreciate any help you guys can offer. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The "<rc 2>" message tells you the process exited with a returncode of `2`, which is an error. You can see the error message by logging `${fish.stderr}`.

Robot uses `\` as an escape character. You should use `/` instead -- `/` is perfectly valid as a path separator on windows.

```
${fish}=  Run Process    python   C:/PyCharm/Automation/HelloWorld.py
```

Comment: Thanks for that. So it is returning rc 0 now, which seems like a success in the process execution, at least. But I'm still not getting "Hello World" displaying in the run console.

Comment: @JustinHooks: correct. The output is returned when you run the process. This is documented as part of the library documentation. In your case you can use `${fish.stdout}` to access the output.

Answer (score 0):

There is easier way to do it, you can import your python script as library and use Python function as keyword.

Let's assume you have a function

```
def print_hello_world():
  return "Hello world"
```

You can import it as library and use function as keyword like this

```
*** Settings ***
Library  hello_world.py

*** Test Cases ***
Sample Test
  ${text}=  Print Hello World
  Log To Console  ${text}
```